# Rendimiento y tuning de Vista MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, rendimiento

, necesito su ayuda y conocimientos para poder mejorar esta vista que les presento en MySQL. Esta demorando bastante y quiero reducir los tiempos de carga.

Tengo poco manejo de Sql y T-Sql. Podrian ayudarme con el formato de esta vista aplicando buenas practicas o mejorando el diseño de la misma?.

Saludos y gracias!

```
SELECT
ENCA.ID AS ID,
ENCA.FECHA AS DATE,
CONCAT(P.SKU,'-',P.NOMRBE,' ',P.MARCA_REAL) AS PRODUCT,
(SELECT U.EMAIL FROM USERS U WHERE U.ID=ENCA.ID_USER) AS EMAIL_USER,
C.DESCRIPCION AS CHANEL,
PDV.NOMBRE AS NAME_PDV,
DIST.NOMBRE AS NAME_DISTRIBUTION,
CAT.DESCRIPCION AS CATEGORY,
RTA_MIX.ID_PDV AS ID_PDV,
RTA_MIX.PRECIO_MIN AS MIN_PRICE,
RTA_MIX.PRECIO_MAX AS MAX_PRICE,
RTA_MIX.ANSWER AS ANSWER,
TIPO_CLIENTE.DESCRIPCION AS REGION,
RTA_ENC.ANSWER AS POP,
ENCA.ID AS ID_RELEASE,
(SELECT U.USUARIO_NOMBRE FROM USERS U WHERE U.ID=ENCA.ID_USER) AS RELEVANT,
TIPO_PDV.DESCRIPTION AS TYPEPDV,
CONCAT(PRODUCTO.SKU,' (',PRODUCTO.MARCA_REAL,' ',PRODUCTO.NOMBRE,')') AS PRODUCT,
CONCAT(ENCA.FECHA,'-',PDV.NOMBRE) AS DATEPDV

FROM
ENCABEZADO_RESULTADO_ENCUESTA ENCA
JOIN RESPUESTA_MIX RTA_MIX
ON ENCA.ID=RTA_MIX.ID_ENCABEZADO
JOIN PRODUCTO P
ON P.ID=RTA_MIX.ID_PROCDUCTO
JOIN CANAL C
ON C.ID=ENCA.ID_CANAL
JOIN CATEGORIA CAT
ON CAT.ID=P.ID_CATEGORIA
JOIN PDV_TRADICIONAL PDV
ON PDV.ID=RTA_MIX.ID_PDV
JOIN DISTRIBUIDOR DIST
ON DIST.ID=PDV.ID_DISTRIBUIDOR
JOIN RESPUESYA_ENCUESTA RTA_ENC
ON RTA_ENC.ID_ENCABEZADO=ENCA.ID AND RTA_ENC.ID_TIPO_ENCUESTA='41'
JOIN TIPO_CLIENTE TIPO_CLIENTE
ON TIPO_CLIENTE.ID=PDV.ID_TIPO_CLIENTE
JOIN TIPO_PDV TIPO_PDV
ON TIPO_PDV.ID = RTA_MIX.ID_TIPO_PDV
JOIN PRODUCTO PRODUCTO
ON PROFUCTO.ID=RTA_MIX.ID_PRODUCTO

WHERE
ENCA.ID_PROCESO = 1 AND ENCA.ID_CANAL = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT
ENCA.ID AS ID,
ENCA.FECHA AS DATE,
CONCAT(P.SKU,'-',P.NOMRBE,' ',P.MARCA_REAL) AS PRODUCT,
(SELECT U.EMAIL FROM USERS U WHERE U.ID=ENCA.ID_USER) AS EMAIL_USER,
C.DESCRIPCION AS CANAL,
CONCAT(PDV.NOMBRE,'-',PDV.CODIGO_CLIENTE) AS NAME_PDV,
CAD.DESCRIPCION AS NAME_DIST,
CAT.DESCRIPCION AS CATEGORY,
RTA_MIX.ID_PDV AS ID_PDV,
RTA_MIX.PRECIO_MIN AS MIN_PRICE,
RTA_MIX.PRECIO_MAX AS MAX_PRICE,
RTA_MIX.ANSWER AS ANSWER,
CADENA.DESCRIPCION AS REGION,
RTA_ENC.ANSWER AS POP,
ENCA.ID AS ID_RELEASE,
(SELECT U.USUARIO_NOMBRE FROM USERS U WHERE U.ID=ENCA.ID_USER) AS RELEVANT,
TIPO_PDV.DESCRIPCION AS PDVTYPE,
CONCAT(PRODUCTO.SKU,'(',PRODUCTO.MARCA_REAL,' ',PRODUCTO.NOMBRE,')') AS PROD,
CONCAT(ENCA.FECHA,'-',PDV.NOMBRE) AS DATEPDV

FROM
ENCABEZADO_RESULTADO_ENCUESTA ENCA
JOIN RESPUESTA_MIX RTA_MIX
ON ENCA.ID = RTA_MIX.ID_ENCABEZADO
JOIN PRODUCTO P
ON P.ID=RTA_MIX.ID_PRODUCTO
JOIN CANAL C
ON C.ID=ENCA.ID_CANAL
JOIN CATEGORIA CAT
ON CAT.ID=P.ID_CATEGORIA
JOIN PDV_MODERNO PDV
ON PDV.ID=RTA_MIX.ID_PDV
JOIN CADENA CAD
ON CAD.ID=PDV.ID_CADENA
JOIN RESPUESTA_ENCUESTA RTA_ENC
ON RTA_ENC.ID_ENCABEZADO = ENCA.ID AND RTA_ENC.ID_TIPO_ENCUESTA='41'
JOIN CADENA
ON CADENA.ID=PDV.ID_CADENA
JOIN TIPO_PDV
ON TIPO_PDV.ID=RTA_MIX.ID_TIPO_PDV
JOIN PRODUCTO
ON PRODUCTO.ID=RTA_MIX.ID_PRODUCTO

WHERE
ENCA.ID_PROCESO = 1 AND ENCA.ID_CANAL = 0
```

Comment: El SQL por sí solo no es suficiente para ayudarte a optimizarlo. Te refiero a [esta publicación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2880/18951) para identificar lo que le falta a tu pregunta para que podamos ayudarte. Adicionalmente, mencionas T-SQL, pero esto es se usa en SQL Server. ¿Cual es tu base de datos, MySQL o SQL Server?

Comment: Tenes algo por lo que empezar que es el **UNION**, si investigas un poco sobre ["Algoritmos de Procesamiento"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-algorithms.html) podrás encontrar que existen dos alrotimos: **merge** y **temptable**. Para lograr mejor performance debes intentar trabajar con **merge**, por lo que hay cosas que debes tener en cuenta, [aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-table-optimization.html) dan consejos acerca de que cosas producen **temptable** (como lo que te sucede a vos) y genera baja performance.

Answer (score 1):

Las dos subconsultas

```
(SELECT U.EMAIL FROM USERS U WHERE U.ID=ENCA.ID_USER) AS EMAIL_USER,
```

y

```
(SELECT U.USUARIO_NOMBRE FROM USERS U WHERE U.ID=ENCA.ID_USER) AS RELEVANT,
```

No son necesarias. Puedes obtener esos valores mediante un `JOIN`.

Simplificando (para no incluir todos los campos)

```
SELECT
    ENCA.ID AS ID,
    ENCA.FECHA AS DATE,
    U.EMAIL AS EMAIL_USER,
    U.USUARIO_NOMBRE as RELEVANT

FROM
ENCABEZADO_RESULTADO_ENCUESTA ENCA
JOIN USERS U ON U.ID=ENCA.ID_USER
```

Esto aplica para las dos consultas que forman tu vista.

Para optimizar más, habría que ver si todos los joins le pegan a índices en las respectivas tablas.